# Is there a flag that tells Zebra printers to include the check digit in the textual representation of a barcode?

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, .net-1.1, zebra-printers

I am sending CPCL commands from a handheld device to a Zebra QL220 printer to print barcode labels. It seems that when the barcode prints, the barcode value is correct (it incorporates/appends the check digit to the machine-readable swath of vertical black (and/or white) stripes), but the check digit is not incorporated/appended to the Text representation (below the barcode).

IOW, the barcode may represent "123456789014" but the text value is "12345678901" (it's lacking the check digit).

Is there an easy way to "turn this on," such as via one of the flags sent to the printer via CPCL, or will I have to manually manipulate the Text value to display the check digit appended to the barcode?

Comment: What symbology are you trying to print?

Comment: Many, depending on the length (thus deducing the type) of the barcode it changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the CPCL manual (page 5.17: https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/comtec/PROMAN-CPCL_RevY.pdf ) and the ZPL manual (https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/zpl_manual.pdf), there appears to be no documented command flag that will cause a printer to print the checksum in the barcode interpretation line.  I think you will have to include it yourself.